# column operations on jagged arrays (sum, average, other functions) with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, jagged-arrays

Assuming we have a jagged array with equal length item arrays (i.e. ignore catching out of ranges):

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[][] 
{
    new int[] {1, 3, 5},
    new int[] {0, 2, 4},
    new int[] {11,22,6}
};
```

what is the most elegant way to apply c# Linq to perform column operations. Example results for simple column operations Sum and Average:

Sum() column result: int[] {12, 27, 15 }
Average() column result: int[] {4, 9, 5 }
...any other similar extension method that operates on a column.

The closest related question I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088561/sum-columns-of-a-2d-array).

Thanks for the answers, I have accepted Jay's answer and also posted a similar but much more complicated aggregation of columns on an Enumerable question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544070/efficient-column-operations-sum-average-on-very-large-enumerablearraytype).

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you need to use LINQ, i.e. are other "elegant" solutions not valid?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes sure other options are valid/straight forward of course (I currently do the same in your typical loop) - but am interested in any elegant linq solution to use with a delegate - my attempts looked like the question I liked - i.e. rather messy.

Comment: LINQ is much slower than doing the job with two for loops. In performance matter cases, do not use LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  var results = Enumerable.Range(0, jaggedArray[0].Length)
    .Select(i => jaggedArray.Sum(a => a[i]))
    .ToArray();
```

Substitute `Sum` with `Average` *etc.*

Comment: Note: jaggedArray.Length is not the same as the column count.

Comment: @Keith Thanks; I mistranscribed it -- should've been `jaggedArray[0].Length`.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetColumnValues(IEnumerable<int[]> arr, int columnIndex)
{
    return arr.Select(a => a.Skip(columnIndex).FirstOrDefault());
}
...
GetColumnValues(jaggedArray, 1).Sum();
```

for all column computation use Enumerable.Range

```
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(columnIndex => GetColumnValues(jaggedArray, columnIndex).Sum());
```