# Efficient column operations (sum, average...) on very large Enumerable<arrayType[]> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, stream, ienumerable

Assuming we have the following IEnumerable example:

```
IEnumerable<int[]> veryLargeJaggedArray =
{
   new int[] {1, 3, 5},
   new int[] {0, 2, 4},
   new int[] {11,22,6},
   ...lots of data streaming in
}
```

where the underlying collection is not based on ICollection (i.e. no fast Count() lookup), what is the most efficient way to apply c# Linq to perform aggregate type column operations?

This question extends my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542384/column-operations-on-jagged-arrays-sum-average-other-functions-with-linq) to a more practical case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create your own method to generate a sequence representing a column given that input:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetColumn<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IList<T>> data, 
    int columnNumber)
{
    return data.Select(row => row[columnNumber]);
}
```

Now you can write code like:

```
var firstColumnSum = veryLargeJaggedArray.GetColumn(0).Sum();
var secondColumnAverage = veryLargeJaggedArray.GetColumn(1).Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in extension methods are already pretty smart. You typically just need something like this:

```
var result = MyCollection.Sum();
```

or

```
var result = MyCollection.Average(i => i.NumericProperty);
```

These extension methods take advantage of overloading and polymorphism, such that if your underlying collection type implements `IList<T>`, that version of the method (which can take advantage of a Count property) will be called, but if only `IEnumerable<T>` is available, then the `IEnumerable<T>` will run.

Comment: He's acting on a sequence of arrays, not just a flat sequence, as such neither of those options would compile.